# NimbusLeaderNotFoundException in Apache Storm UI

Tags: scala, user-interface, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am trying to launch Storm ui for streaming application, however I constantly get this error:

```
org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [localhost]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:250)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:138)
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.ui.resources.StormApiResource.getClusterConfiguration(StormApiResource.java:116)
```

I have launched storm locally using storm script for starting nimbus, submitting jar and polling ui. What could be the reason of it?

Here is the code with connection setup:

```
 val cluster = new LocalCluster()
    val bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092"
    val spoutConfig = KafkaTridentSpoutConfig.builder(bootstrapServers, "tweets")
      .setProp(props)
      .setFirstPollOffsetStrategy(FirstPollOffsetStrategy.LATEST)
      .build()

  val config = new Config()
    cluster.submitTopology("kafkaTest", config, tridentTopology.build())
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Do you want to run Storm in memory using LocalCluster, or do you want to submit a topology to an already running Storm cluster using the "storm jar" command?

Comment: I was running it as a local application but it does not allow to access Storm UI so I packaged it into a jar file and submitted to the storm cluster.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit to a real cluster using `storm jar`, you should not use LocalCluster. Instead use the `StormSubmitter` class.

The error you're getting is saying that it can't find Nimbus at localhost. Are you sure Nimbus is running on the machine you're running `storm jar` from? If so, please post the commands you're running, and maybe also check the Nimbus log.